# Synchronizing 2 seperate speech audio signals

Tags: audio, cross-correlation, speech-processing, mfcc, synchronization

I have two speech signals: one with a man reading a passage, and one with a woman reading the same passage.

I want to synchronize these signals so that, for each word, their readings line up. The problem is that the differences in the signals are heterogeneous. Sometimes, the man will read a word slightly faster, and sometimes the woman will read the word faster. The length of their pauses could similarly be different on a per-pause basis.

Is there a slick automatic way of syncing these that's robust to noise?

My guess at a solution algorithm is to

1. Find the segment of the signal containing the next word in the male signal, and similarly for the female signal.
2. Stretch/contract the male/female segments to align in length, and then move onto the next word.

Obviously, when I say stretch/contract, I mean without changing the pitch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer. It's [Dynamic Time Warping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_time_warping), which is a play on the edit distance algorithm. A python implementation for audio signals can be found [here](https://librosa.github.io/librosa_gallery/auto_examples/plot_music_sync.html).